# const qualifier removed on getter if template argument is a pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, gcc

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct Val
{
    T val;

    const T& get() const { return val; }
    void set(const T& newVal) { val = newVal; }
};

int& f(const Val<int>& val)
{
    return val.get();
}

int* g(const Val<int*>& val)
{
    return val.get();
}

int main()
{
    Val<int> val1;
    f(val1);

    Val<int*> val2;
    g(val2);

    return 0;
}
```

It fails compilation in gcc with the following message:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int& f(const Val<int>&)':
main.cpp:78:20: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'int&' from expression of type 'const int'
     return val.get();
                    ^
main.cpp:79:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

That's totally fine, but why isn't the same error produced for `g()`? Why, for some reason, is the const qualifier removed on `const T&`, when `T` is a pointer?

I tried to find some resources, but it seems hard to find. I know Meyers wrote something in his newest book, but I don't have access to that one. Can someone point me to resources or keywords where I could find more on that whole topic of template type deduction when `T` is a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why, for some reason, is the const qualifier removed on const T&, when T is a pointer?

Because you're returning the pointer by value, not by reference. It is perfectly fine to initialize a pointer from a const pointer (note it is the pointers that are `const`, not the things they point to.) You're doing the equivalent of this:

```
int* const p0 = nullptr; // const pointer
int* p1 = p0;            // copy to non-const is OK
```

If you were to initialize a non-cost reference to poiter from a const pointer, you'd get a similar error to the first case:

```
// error: binding of reference to type 'int *'
// to a value of type 'int *const' drops qualifiers
int*& p1 = p;
```

Comment: Now I see, of course. In `const T&` the `const` guards the whole `T`, not the value within.

Comment: @bobbel I don't really know what you mean by that.

Comment: Sorry, yeah confusing. Not important. Discovered an error in my thinking. I expected `Val<int>` and `Val<int*>` to have the same behavior on the inner `int`.